# Inserir dados no contato a partir do aplicativo

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se é possível inserir algum dado no contato do telefone, por exemplo o e-mail. 
Exemplificando:
Ao selecionar um contato, a partir do aplicativo, ao voltar a activity, é solicitado a inserção do e-mail e este ficar gravado no contato, do telefone.

Isto é possível? Se sim, há algum exemplo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar a seguinte abordagem:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                        edtNome.getEditText().getText().toString()).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                        edtEmail.getEditText().getText().toString()).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        edtTelefone.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());

        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResult = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            if (contentProviderResult[0].uri == null) {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao incluir usuário");
            } else {
                new SnackBar.Builder(this)
                        .withMessage("Usuário incluído aos contatos com sucesso!")
                        .withStyle(SnackBar.Style.DEFAULT)
                        .withDuration((short) 3000)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Tens que repassar o Contact_ID como parâmetro para saber que se trata de uma edição, caso for inclusão, ele irá com 0.

Comment: O if (contentProviderResult[0].uri == null) { que fiz não é obrigatório, no meu caso tratei ele para saber se houve sucesso na inserção.

Comment: O exemplo acima são algumas dicas, email, podes estudar esse trecho:

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                        edtEmail.getEditText().getText().toString()).build());

Comment: Carlos, obrigado. Vou estudar sim e assim que o fizer, marco como resposta ou coloco minhas dúvidas.